# Any geo libraries for javascript out there?

Tags: javascript

I've been searching for a library to make easier geo tasks. For example, calculating the distance between two points.

I've seen methods written in some blogs and websites, but I would like to know some "complete" library.

Are you using one?

Thanks!

PS: I'm not referring to geocoding libraries, although I don't mind if it includes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/). Then again, this is an API and not a downloadable library. It may be able to help you though... or could be way overkill for what you're wanting.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer [Proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/) together with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) over the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/).